# Can't connect to MySQL from PHP script running on the PHP builtin server (localhost)

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I am trying to connect to the MySQL service provided by XAMPP ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN1O4.png)) through a PHP script that runs on the builtin PHP server (I started the server through `php -S localhost:4242` in the folder where I have the scripts). However, when I try to connect to the database, I receive this error:

> Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

In my connection script, I have:

```
class DB
{
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = 'root';
    private $pwd = '';
    private $dbname = 'mydb';

    public function create_connection() {
        $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
          }

        return $conn;
    }
}
```

When I call `create_connection()` I receive the error above. The MySQLi extension is enabled in my PHP. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I don't want to move everything to XAMPP's **htdocs**, I would like to access MySQL from the scripts outside.

**Update** The problem was solved. The issue was confusion between instance/class variables, and now connection works. The correct statement is:

`$conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pwd, $this->dbname);`

Comment: you are running a user root with no password?

Comment: @Keltari yes, locally. It works from the console. If I run `mysql -u root -p`, I can connect.

Comment: I would perhaps try `127.0.0.1` rather than `localhost`. Also you may want to test a simple connection without variables, classes or additional code e.g. `$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", 3306);`. You could then `echo` the output e.g. `echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
`.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Gosh, thanks. That solved it. It was a stupid mistake, indeed those weren't static variables but member fields, and `$host, $user`, etc. were actually empty.

Comment: Your welcome. And that makes sense. Glad you figured out where the trouble was. =)